# Rails using variables for column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Like model, it connects users liking items. Additonally to the standard `liked` status, items can be `spinned` & `pinned`, all being boolean fields.

**Like Model**

```
 _________________________________________________
| item_id | user_id |  liked  |  spinned | pinned |
|---------|---------|---------|----------|--------|
|    1    |    1    |  true   |   true   | false  |
|    2    |    1    |  false  |   true   | true   |
|    3    |    2    |  true   |   false  | false  |
 -------------------------------------------------
```

The different states of an item all get updated via the same `AJAX` call, calling the same `action` in my `likes controller`. When the like does not yet exist, it creates a like with the desired state being true.

**likes_controller**

```
def index
  # get the item id
  action = params[:act]
  mid = params[:mid]

  # gets the desired like item to see if it already exists
  like = Like.where(:item_id => mid, :user_id => current_user.id).first

  case action

    # like the item
    when "like"
      # if the item doesn't exist
      if like.blank?
        # create the like
        Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => mid, :liked => true)
      else
        # else toggle the liked status
        like.toggle! :liked
      end

    # pin the item
    when "pin"
      if like.blank?
        # create the like
        Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => mid, :pinned => true)
      else
        # else toggle the pinned status
        like.toggle! :pinned
      end

    # spin the item
    when "spin"
      if like.blank?
        # create the like
        Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => mid, :spinned => true)
      else
        # else toggle the spinned status
        like.toggle! :spinned
      end
  end
end
```

As you see, the code in the `case` gets very repetitive, I wanted to know if I could use my `action` ('like', 'pin', 'spin') variable more effectively.

I could easily convert the `action` to the appropriate field name ("like" => "liked", "pin" => "pinned", "spin" => "spinned") by sending another parameter value from my `view`.

Could I then use this to only have one block of code instead of 3 similar ones?

**iE**

```
action = "liked" # this would change depending on the desired action

# if the item doesn't exist
if like.blank?
  # original
  Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => mid, :liked => true)
  # doesn't work, how would I do this appropriately?
  Like.create("user_id = ?, item_id = ?, ? = true", current_user.id, mid, action)
else
  # this works!, what about SQL injection? How can I prevent this?
  like.toggle!("#{action}")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I could simply use my variable `action` instead of the column selector `:column` when using `create()` and `toggle()`.

The result being:

```
if like.blank?
  # create the like
  Like.create(:user_id => current_user, :item_id => mid, action => true)
else
  # else toggle the desired status
  like.toggle!(action)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use select or new and then save if the atomicity of events is not a major issue.

```
like = Like.where(:item_id => mid, :user_id => current_user.id).first
like ||= Like.new(:item_id => mid, :user_id => current_user.id, :pinned => false, :spinned => false, :liked => false)
when "like"
like.liked = !like.liked
when "spin"
like.spinned = !like.spinned
when "pin"
like.pinned = !like.pinned
end
like.save!
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the select or new operator, I implemented it rightaway! My solution to toggling the states is easier.